# Proving $n^2=n$, $n$ is even and $n$ is greater than $0$ is false

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am wondering if I have made a wrong jump in logic with my answering to this question.

The original statement goes "There exists an integer $n$ such that $n^2=n$, $n$ is even and $n$ is greater than $0$".

I have taken the approach of first defining that if $n$ is even, than $n=2k$ where $k$ is of the set of integers.

I have then substituted this into $n^2=n$ by saying that $(2k)^2=(2k)$, and as such $2k=1$. Given this I have concluded it to be false as there is no integer $k$ such that $2k=1$.

I am worried about this logic though because if $n$ is equal to $0$ (which is an even number that fits the definition of $2k$) then $n^2=n$ is true which seems to go against my previous logic (which is where the final comparison to $n$ having to be greater than $0$ would come in).

Am I right in being worried about the direction I have taken this logic? If so where have I gone wrong in my line of thinking? Thank you for all help.

Comment: To get $2k=1$ you divided both sides by $k$. But if $n=0$ then $k=0$.

Comment: You can't divide by $2k$ if $2k=0$, because we don't divide things by $0$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying on that, I hadn't considered that important detail at all in my assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *did* (implicitly) make use of the assumption that $n > 0$.  Since $n >0$, your $k$ cannot be $0$.  Thus it is okay to divide by $k$, which you did in your proof when you moved from $4k^2=2k$ down to $2k=1$.

Good for you for thinking about this!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see now the implicit assumption that I made.

Answer (score 3):

We have $n^2=n$ implies $n^2-n=0$, *i.e.*, $$n(n-1)=0.$$ Thus either $n=0$ or $n=1$, but, by hypothesis, both these options are impossible. (They are the only possible solutions by inspection and the [fundamental theorem of  algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra); moreover, by the quadratic formula,

$$\begin{align}
n&=\frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4(1)(0)}}{2(1)}\\
&=\frac{1\pm 1}{2}\\
&=0\text{ or }1.)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I am not quite sure I fully understand this implication? I see that if n^2=n then n=1 then n-1=0 where n is not equal to 0. How were you able to get n(n-1)=0 from this may I ask?

Comment: I've edited my answer, @James. Does that help?

Comment: That does help, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome, @James.

Comment: $$n^2=0$$ $$n^2 - n = 0$$ Factorizing, $$n(n - 1) = 0$$ and you can do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The flaw lies in the implication

$$(2k)^2=2k\implies 2k=1.$$

This claim is indeed false when $k=0$.

$$0=0\not\Longrightarrow 0=1.$$

Comment: Notice that no "division by zero" argument is necessary.